# Kibana visualization based on fields

Tags: visualization, kibana

I am new to the field on ELK ,while using Kibana for visualization i only get the count on the Y axis

I have the below data

```
{"command":"write","inputmethod":"aufs","bw":"2000.0", "iops":"512000", "runt":"3msec", "slatAvg":"1.98", "clatAvg":"0.27"}

{"command":"read","inputmethod":"vfs", "bw":"2000.0", "iops":"512000", "runt":"3msec", "slatAvg":"1.91", "clatAvg":"0.29"}

{"command":"readwrite","inputmethod":"devicemapper", "runtRead":"22msec", "runtWrite":"22msec", "iopsRead":"39272", "iopsWrite":"30545", "bwRead":"157091", "bwWrite":"122182", "slatAvgRead":"122.06", "slatAvgWrite":"16.82", "clatAvgRead":"0.32", "clatAvgWrite":"0.31" }
```

I have the three types of inuput method "aufs","vfs" and "devicemapper",I want to say visualize the iops of three methods .Say my x axis will be aufs ,vfs,devicemapper and my y axis is iops

```
iops
!  !
!  !    !
!  !    !         ! 
!----------------------
  aufs  vds    devicemapper
```

Can some one please advice.

Answer (score 0):

In Discover left panel, click on your "inputmethod" field (not on "add" button).

Then you will see a new block called "Quick count", click on "Visualize" button.

On Visualize dashboard, you will have a configured vertical bar chart.

Simply click on the small arrow at the left of "Y-Axis". Change "Count" by "Average". A new "Field" will appear, choose finally : "iops". Preview and it's done.

Of course, you can use "Sum", "Median", "Min"...etc instead of "Average".